# Can a door control system deal with more than 1 door

Tags: prison-architect

My prison entrance has a 2 door system that always slows people down. I'd like to replace these with remote doors, but I cant seem to get the second door wired up. It seems like the game is only allowing me to wire up one servo per door control system, but that feels weird. I thought I saw instances where one door control system can control multiple doors. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect the door control system to the servos, and not the other way around. If you connect the servo to the control system, it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed possible, door control systems can control multiple doors.  I do not know if there is an upper limit - I haven't encountered it myself.

[image: Remote door system with multiple inputs]

As you can see the above door system is running with 8 outputs without difficulty.

[image: Zoomed out picture of multiple input door system showing servo connections]

This was achieved by simply clicking the connect tool, then the door control system, then each servo in turn.  This has worked for me in the previous two alphas (24/23).

Having just attempted to recreate this to be sure it wasn't an emerging bug I can confirm that it still works - the rendering of the wires could be making it appear like you can only chose one, though.  Check by mousing over the door control system (rather than the servo) or by clicking the show wires button.

Comment: Although a door control station can be connected to a number of doors the time taken to actuate a door increases. So with many doors connected it can take a while for the guard to open a door, causing bottlenecks.

Comment: The time limit, according to one of the dev videos, is 2 doors/second. So the more doors on a single control, the slower, but if you have many rarely used or used at different times doors and just a couple crowded doors, they could all do well on one control.